# Ajax serialize with other parameters,

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am very close on this working. I am just having issues with one variable (q3).

I have been working to get some data into a database using ajax, php and MySQL. It is all working except **question 3**. All of the data submits but question 3, in the database, is always empty...

Does anyone have any ideas? I am new to using serialize() but logging it in the console shows a string of all checked boxes.

Please note this is only a subset of code. **Thank you.**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="question3" class="question_block" style="display:block;">

    <p class=""><b>3. If you don’t use the bus system, please let us know why (pick your top 3 reasons):</b></p>

    <input type="checkbox" name="question3_answer[]" class="question3_answer" value="Buses do not go where I want to go" /> Buses do not go where I want to go
    <input type="checkbox" name="question3_answer[]" class="question3_answer" value="Buses do not run when I need it" /> Buses do not run when I need it
    <input type="checkbox" name="question3_answer[]" class="question3_answer" value="Buses are too crowded" /> Buses are too crowded
    <input type="checkbox" name="question3_answer[]" class="question3_answer" value="Buses are too crowded" /> Buses are unreliable
    <input type="checkbox" name="question3_answer[]" class="question3_answer" value="Transfers between bus routes are difficult" /> Transfers between bus routes are difficult
    <input type="checkbox" name="question3_answer[]" class="question3_answer" value="Waiting times are too long" /> Waiting times are too long
    <input type="checkbox" name="question3_answer[]" class="question3_answer" value="I don’t live near a bus route" /> I don’t live near a bus route
    <input id="question3_other" type="checkbox" name="" class="question3_answer other" value="other" />Other:
    <input type="text" id="question3_textanswer" name="question3_answer[]" class="question3_answer" placeholder="Your answer here" style="width:40%;display:none;">

    <button id="toPlay" onclick="submit_1();">Submit and continue</button>
</div>
```

**Ajax:**

```
function submit_1() {
        var q1 = document.getElementById("question1_answer").value;
        var q2 = document.getElementById("question2_answer").value;
        var q3 = $('.question3_answer:checked').serialize();
        var q4 = document.getElementById("question4_answer").value;
        var q5 = document.getElementById("question5_answer").value;

        var dataString = 'question1_answer=' + q1 + '&question2_answer=' + q2 + '&question3_answer=' + q3 + '&question4_answer=' + q4 + '&question5_answer=' + q5;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "php/video_form_process.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                alert(html);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['question1_answer'])) {
// Gets data from URL parameters
$question1_answer = $_POST['question1_answer'];
$question2_answer = $_POST['question2_answer'];
$question3_answer = $_POST['question3_answer'];
$question4_answer = $_POST['question4_answer'];
$question5_answer = $_POST['question5_answer'];

    $query= "INSERT INTO `responses` (`uid`, `time`, `q1`,`q2`,`q3`,`q4`,`q5`, `ipaddr`) VALUES ('', '$today','$question1_answer','$question2_answer','$question3_answer','$question4_answer','$question5_answer')";

    if ($query_run = mysqli_query($server, $query)) {
        echo 'success';
    } else {
        echo 'error';
    }
}
```

**WORKING Ajax:**

```
    function submit_1() {
        var q1 = $(".question1_answer:checked").val();
        var q2 = document.getElementById("question2_answer").value;

        var q3 = [];
        $(".question3_answer:checked").each(function() {
            q3.push($(this).val());
        });

        var q4 = document.getElementById("question4_answer").value;
        var q5 = document.getElementById("question5_answer").value;

        var dataString = 'question1_answer=' + q1 + '&question2_answer=' + q2 + '&question3_answer=' + q3 + '&question4_answer=' + q4 + '&question5_answer=' + q5;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "php/video_form_process.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                alert(html);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

**WORKING PHP:**

```
if (isset($_POST['question1_answer'])) {
// Gets data from URL parameters
$question1_answer = mysqli_real_escape_string($server, $_POST['question1_answer']);
$question2_answer = mysqli_real_escape_string($server, $_POST['question2_answer']);
$question3_answer = mysqli_real_escape_string($server, $_POST['question3_answer']);
$question4_answer = mysqli_real_escape_string($server, $_POST['question4_answer']);
$question5_answer = mysqli_real_escape_string($server, $_POST['question5_answer']);

$query= "INSERT INTO `responses`
         (`time`, `q1`,`q2`,`q3`,`q4`,`q5`, `ipaddr`)
         VALUES ('{$today}', '{$question1_answer}', '{$question2_answer}', '{$question3_answer}', '{$question4_answer}', '{$question5_answer}', '127.0.0.1')";

if ($query_run = mysqli_query($server, $query)) {
    echo 'success';
} else {
    echo 'error';
}
```

}

Comment: I'm surprised how did you got all input values?.......you r each input field has same id....

Comment: ids are singular... `id="question3_answer"` <-- multiple elements with same id is invalid

Comment: Just going to put it out there, using the `<select>` HTML element would be much more user friendly and "clean".. It will also save you having to write unnecessary code.

Comment: @epascarello, thanks, I missed that. removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this to post value.

using array push you can add your checkbox value in s3 variable see below code.

```
    var s3=[];
    $("input:checked").each(function() {
       s3.push($(this).val());
    });
```

Comment: Logging s3 results in the following for example **["Buses do not go where I want to go", "Buses do not run when I need it"]**. This column in the database is still empty, the rest are being populated.

Answer (score 1):

Some advice ...

**JS**

1. use an object for your `data`, not a string
2. you can use `map` to create an array of ids or something from checkes elements
3. add `dataType` to your ajax, to be sure

**PHP**

5. where is your `$today` declared? are you sure it is there?
6. remove `uid` from sql query when it's empty
7. escape the values
8. escape your sql query
9. you set no IP address in your values

**JS**

```
function submit_1() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/video_form_process.php",
        dataType: "html",
        data: {
            question1_answer = $("#question1_answer").val(),
            question2_answer = $("#question2_answer").val(),
            question3_answer = $(".question3_answer:checked").map(function() {
                return $(this).val();
            }).get().join(","),
            question4_answer = $("#question4_answer").val(),
            question5_answer = $("#question5_answer").val()
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            alert(html);
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['question1_answer'])) {
    // Gets data from URL parameters
    $question1_answer = mysqli_real_escape_string($server, $_POST['question1_answer']);
    $question2_answer = mysqli_real_escape_string($server, $_POST['question2_answer']);
    $question3_answer = mysqli_real_escape_string($server, $_POST['question3_answer']);
    $question4_answer = mysqli_real_escape_string($server, $_POST['question4_answer']);
    $question5_answer = mysqli_real_escape_string($server, $_POST['question5_answer']);

    $query= "INSERT INTO `responses`
             (`time`, `q1`, `q2`, `q3`, `q4`, `q5`, `ipaddr`)
             VALUES ('{$today}', '{$question1_answer}', '{$question2_answer}', '{$question3_answer}', '{$question4_answer}', '{$question5_answer}', '127.0.0.1')";

    if ($query_run = mysqli_query($server, $query)) {
        echo 'success';
    } else {
        echo 'error';
    }
}
```

Comment: This is resulting in **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;** for **question1_answer = mysqli_real_escape_string($server, $_POST['question1_answer']);**. Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't your `$server` variable the link response from `mysqli_connect`?

Comment: Yikes, my mistake, I didn't scroll enough. It is for the line.... **question1_answer = $("#question1_answer").val();** in the JS.

Comment: Ahh, my fault. I used `;` instead of `,`. Fixed.

Comment: I also had a missing `{` in the mysql query. Fixed too.

Comment: Okay. Logging q3 i am seeing **question3_answer%5B%5D=Transfers+between+bus+routes+are+difficult&question3_answer%5B%5D=Waiting+times+are+too+long&question3_answer%5B%5D=I+don%E2%80%99t+live+near+a+bus+route** and the database column is still not populating...  Also, my mistake but there is a missing ' at echo error';

Comment: Could you log the `$question3_answer` on your php side? To see what your sql query will get.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help. Ehcoing out $question3_answer shows nothing, blank. I did combine your PHP code, and some of your pointers, with a modified version of @Nikhil Vaghla answer and it is all working... Again, you are super helpful and knowledgeable.

Comment: Great it worked now! But I would like to understand how you use the code from Nikhil. I dont see why it works and my example don't. Can you show me your new code? Thanks!

Comment: I have edited the question with the working code at the bottom. Again, thanks so much. I learned a lot from you.

Comment: Ahh, damn. Found my fault. I forgot `.get()` behind the `map` in ajax. Now the code works fine and could be used. I'm angry about myself now.

Comment: But you really should go with an data object instead of a string. It is easy to maintain, best to view, less code and more native than string action. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of computing the data to send through Ajax, just use `$(FORM_ID).serialize()` where `FORM_ID` is a selector which selects your form.
And in the ajax call this line `data: dataString,` becomes `$(FORM_ID).serialize(),`

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the OP's question. Please save "answers" for answers; and suggestions for comments.

Answer (score -2):

Your code should be

```
function submit_1() {
        var q1 = document.getElementById("question1_answer").value;
        var q2 = document.getElementById("question2_answer").value;
        var q4 = document.getElementById("question4_answer").value;
        var q5 = document.getElementById("question5_answer").value;

        var q3 = [];
        $('input[type="checkbox"][name="question3_answer[]"]:checked').each(function(){
            q3.push($(this).val());
        })

        var dataPost = {
            question1_answer:  q1, 
            question2_answer: q2, 
            question3_answer: q3, 
            question4_answer: q4, 
            question5_answer: q5
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "php/video_form_process.php",
            data: dataPost,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                alert(html);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: No idea, I did not down vote. I did try this and logging this only returns **Buses do not go where I want to go** even though I selected three check boxes.